# How to add custom onRowClick function for a field in Material Table?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Hello I want to add a on Row Click to link to another window with id from my api?

```
<div className="table-responsive">
  <MaterialTable
    title="Filter/Search/Sort by Column Attribute"
    columns={[
      { title: 'Name', field: 'player_name_last_first' },
```

I want to add that functionality for Name, also the link must include the id which is field: player_id , how can I include that?

Comment: Hi, take a look at the last example (bottom of the page) of the [material-documentation](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/detail-panel). Should be self-explanatory.

Comment: just for one column though?

Answer (score 0):

You can try rendering a custom div on each cell of the column with your redirect logic onClick.

i.e

```
<div className="table-responsive">
  <MaterialTable
    title="Filter/Search/Sort by Column Attribute"
    columns={[
      { title: 'Name', 
        field: 'player_name_last_first',
        render: (rowData) => 
               <div onClick={ () => { // Your redirect logic with rowData.player_id }>
                  {rowData.player_name_last_first}
               </div>
     }
```